# Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals in impulse response?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, filter, response, subscript

I want to find the impulse response of this causal system

```
y(n) = 0.32x(n) + 0.68x(n-1) + 0.4x(n-2) - 0.6y(n-2)
0≤n≤100
```

When I use the `filter` function everything works fine, the code is here:

```
figure(1)
n=[0:100];
d=inline('n==0');
a=[1 0.6 ];   % y
b=[0.32 0.68 0.4]; %  x 
y=filter(b, a, d(n));
stem(n, y);
```

But when i try this code it gives me this message:

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

What am I doing wrong?

```
% y(n) = 0.32x(n) + 0.68x(n-1) + 0.4x(n-2) - 0.6y(n-2) 
% y(n) = h(n) kai x(n) = d(n).

n=0:100;
h(1:length(n))=0;
d=inline('n==0');
h(1)=1;
for i=2:length(n)
h(i) = 0.32*d(n(i)) + 0.68*d(n(i)-1)+ 0.4*d(n(i)-2) - 0.6*h(i-2);
end 
stem(n,h)
```

Comment: It means you're trying to index the array with a non-positive value.

Comment: here `h(i-2)` you are trying to access element in index `0`, while indexes in MATLAB starts at `1`.

Comment: @user2999345 Thank you so much you really helped me out ! :)